# 物理型レプリケーションのデータ抜けについて

Tags: postgresql, database

あるシステムでPostgreSQL（9.3.2）をレプリケーション稼動させています。

レプリケーション構成は`synchronous_commit=local` の非同期です。

物理型のレプリケーション方式で且つ、非同期レプリケーション構成の場合、
論理型のレプリケーション（MySQL等）で発生しうる様なプライマリからスタンバイへのデータの同期漏れの可能性がないかどうかを確認したいです。

完全同期の場合はスタンバイへのデータ抜けの可能性がないことは理解できますが、
非同期の場合、例えばWAL転送時のTCP等で問題が発生した場合にWALトランザクションの幾つかの同期が漏れて、その分のスタンバイのデータが歯抜けになってしまう状態があり得るかどうかというところが知りたいところです。

確認する方法や、仮に同期漏れの可能性がある場合に、検知できるような仕組みがあるかどうか等の回答でも結構です。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「トランザクションの同期が漏れる」とは、どういう状況なのでしょうか。

Comment: `A` と `B` という順番のトランザクションがあるとすれば、Aが同期されず、Bが同期されるという様な状況です。

Comment: 想定の場合、通常はaが失敗した時点でエラーですよね。エラーログ環視してエラー検知させるのはだめですか？エラーログすらはかない状況ならプロセスどうにかしてるんで、その前に何らかのエラー掃きそうですね。あとはプロセスの死活環視をどこまでやるかです。

Comment: 現状、 `JSTFATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx has already been removed` の様なログはスタンバイのDBで出力されており、
恐らくこれでエラーは検知できると思っています。

このログが指すセグメントのデータがスタンバイへ反映されていない = マスタとスタンバイのデータにズレが生じてしまうのかどうかという事が一番知りたいところです。


[公式](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.3/html/wal-async-commit.html)では、`ズレは生じない`というようなニュアンスですが、
これはエラーが発生した場合でも言えることなのでしょうか。